# WebView dynamic content size inside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, wkwebview

I'm trying to resize the WKWebView dynamic HTML content inside UICollectionViewCell by referring a `collectionViewCell`. Working fine but sometimes throws a unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at below line:

```
let cell:CollectionViewCell = collectionView!.cellForItem(at: indexpath) as! CollectionViewCell
```

Here is my code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
{
        let indexpath: IndexPath = IndexPath.init(item: self.pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)
        let cell:CollectionViewCell = collectionView!.cellForItem(at: indexpath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.newsWebView?.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
            if result == nil || error != nil {
                return
            }
            cell.newsWebView?.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                if let height = result as? CGFloat {
                    cell.webviewHeightConstraint?.constant = height
                }
            })
    CustomeLoader.instance.hideLoader()
}
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This crash may be due to delay in rendering.

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
       let indexpath: IndexPath = IndexPath.init(item: pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)
        let cell:CollectionViewCell = collectionView!.cellForItem(at: indexpath) as! CollectionViewCell
         cell.newsWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                cell.newsWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                    cell.webviewHeightConstraint.constant = height as! CGFloat
                })
            }

        })         
}
```

Comment: same issue unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at below
let cell:CollectionViewCell = collectionView!.cellForItem(at: indexpath) as! CollectionViewCell. After writing dynamic content code in cellforItem not getting crashed but dynamic content size not getting called.